# Working with MongoLab from .NET - permissions problems

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mlab

I've open an account on MongoLab (free sandbox account for testing). I have code that's running on my local MongoDb server and running just fine without any problems.

In MongoLab I've created a database and created a user for that database and placed the connection string they gave me in my application:

```
 mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@<my_id>.mlab.com:52408/<my_db>
```

I even tried this:

```
 mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@<my_id>.mlab.com:52408/<my_db>?authMode=scram-sha1&rm.tcpNoDelay=true
```

In my .NET code I'm connecting to my database:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(MY_CONNECTION_STRING);
IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("MyTestDb");

_versionRulesCollection = database.GetCollection<VersionRule>("VersionRules");
_versionDetailsCollection = database.GetCollection<VersionDetails>("VersionDetails");
```

but when I try to do something like this:

```
_versionDetailsCollection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<VersionDetails>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.ProductName).Ascending(y => y.DeviceType).Ascending(z => z.VersionName))
```

I get an exception saying

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command createIndexes failed: not authorized on MyTestDb to execute command { createIndexes: "VersionDetails", indexes: [ { key: { ProductName: 1, DeviceType: 1, VersionName: 1 }, name: "ProductName_1_DeviceType_1_VersionName_1" } ] }
```

Even trying to do a query I got:

```
not authorized for query on MyTestDb .VersionDetails
```

I don't see any way to set permission for users on the portal. The database is created dynamically in my app. And I'm at a lost here.

What am I doing wrong (it works on my local machine)?

Comment: could you check role assigned to that user?

Comment: @profesor79 `"role": "dbOwner"`

Comment: I cannot connect at this moment - but wondering if you could try and start mongo session from your box and issue same commands?

Comment: there may be a few potential issues. can you write into support@mlab.com? we can help you there.